Determining Minimal Detectable Effect Using R for a Test of Proportions with Varying Allocations of Sample to Control Vs Test
For an email test, in which we count a success as either responding or not (binomial), we want to know the minimum detectable effect with different proportions of our total sample being assigned to the holdout vs the test group. That is for assignment of control/test, we want to know minimum detectable effect, for 20/80, 75/25,30/70, 65/35,60/40,55/45,50/50. Within the pwr package in R, there is pwr.2p.test function, and this will tell you p1 v p0, but not for different sample sizes. A similar function pwr.2p2n.test will deliver effect size, but in Cohen's H and I cannot figure out how to translate this back into an MDE for proportions. Can anyone demonstrate how i might do this iteratively in R, with a presumed baseline p=.005

Will you be using a one-sided or two-sided test? (in other words, do you want to test if there is an increase relative to $p=.005$, a decrease, or both?). While there might be a solution, the small $p$ may create complications: if you want to test for a decrease, a sample size of 100 (as your question suggests) is probably insufficient to do that with a reasonable power and alpha level. So in this case it would be impossible to convert Cohen's $h$ to another effect size (e.g. risk difference or odds ratio), as there are no minimal effect size possibly detectable.

If you want to test for a decrease but your sample size could be > 100, please mention that, because it's a bit ambiguous from your question (when you say "20/80, 75/25,30/70, 65/35" etc., I'm not sure if you talk about percentages or about raw counts).

You don't describe the software correctly.  The documentation for pwer.wp.test explains how to find the remaining value of h, power, sig.level, and n (the sample size) given values of the other three.  That solves your problem.
